# Angularized Bootstrap Menu Only Collapsing Dropdown, not Entire Navbar after Link Click

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Angularized bootstrap menu that fully collapses the entire navbar if it is loaded in a view, but not when in the index.html. When loaded into my index.html, it only collapses the dropdown and not the whole navbar when an item is clicked on.

I need it in the index.html before the views (data-ng-view) since I have content between the menu and views (AdSense). When placed before my views in the index.html page, if I click on a link, I am able to go that link... but the overall menu stays open instead of closing after going to a link. However, the dropdown will of "Categories" will collapse as intended, it is just the overall menu that won't.

I am using AngularUI and have injected 'ui.bootstrap' into the App (that is how it works when loaded in a view). The controllers for my views are tied to the page they relate to.

Example:

```
when('/home', { templateUrl: './views/home.html', controller: 'homeCtrl' }).
```

Here is my navigation:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-ng-init="isCollapsed = true" data-ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><h1 id="pfch1">My Title</h1></a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" data-ng-class="{collapse: isCollapsed}">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown" data-ng-class="{ open : dd1 }" data-ng-init="dd1 = false" data-ng-click="dd1 = !dd1">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false" href="#">Categories <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="/categories/1/cat1">cat1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/categories/2/cat2">cat2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/categories/5/cat3">cat3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/categories/4/cat4">cat4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/categories/6/cat5">cat5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/categories/3/cat6">cat6</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/add-article">Add Article Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div data-ng-controller="userInfo">
                    <div data-ng-controller="loginCtrl" data-ng-hide="loggedin">
                        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Login" data-ng-click="login()" />
                    </div>
                    <div data-ng-controller="loginCtrl" data-ng-show="loggedin">
                        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Signout" data-ng-click="logout()" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the index.html (please note that the menu above is included via an ng-include. I have tried it without the ng-include but it still doesn't collapse):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" data-ng-app="pfcModule">
<head>
<!-- Inform Search Bots that this is a SPA -->
<meta name="fragment" content="!" />

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="description" content="{{pageDescription | limitTo: 155}}">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../assets/ico/favicon.ico">
<base href="/">
<title>{{pageTitle}}</title>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Just for debuggidata-ng- purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warnidata-ng-.js"></script><![endif]-->
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Container start -->
<div class="container">
    <!-- Top Menu -->
    <div data-ng-include="'templates/topmenu.html'"></div>
    <!-- Responsive AdSense included here -->
    <div data-ng-view></div>
    <!-- Responsive AdSense included here -->
          <hr>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; My Site 2015 | <a href="/termsandconditions">Terms and Conditions</a></p>
    </footer>
</div>
<!-- Container end -->
<!-- Scripts placed at end of Body for execution -->
<script src="js/libs/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/dirPagination.js"></script>

<!-- Auth0 Scripts -->
<!-- We use client cookies to save the user credentials -->
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<!-- Auth0 Lock script and AngularJS module -->
<script src="//cdn.auth0.com/js/lock-6.js"></script>
<!-- angular-jwt and angular-storage -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//rawgit.com/auth0/angular-storage/master/dist/angular-storage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//rawgit.com/auth0/angular-jwt/master/dist/angular-jwt.js"></script>
<!-- Auth0 Scripts -->
<script src="//cdn.auth0.com/w2/auth0-angular-4.0.1.js"> </script>

<!-- Application Scripts -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/addArticle.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/articleID.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/articlesCategory.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/articlesCount.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/articleVoting.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/homeArticles.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/loginManagement.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/modalDependency.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives/directives.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my App.js:

```
var pfcModule = angular.module('pfcModule', [
'ngRoute',
'ui.bootstrap',
'auth0',
'angular-storage',
'angular-jwt',
'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination',
'pfcServices',
'pfcAddArticle',
'pfcArticleID',
'pfcArticlesCategory',
'pfcArticlesCount',
'pfcArticleVoting',
'pfcHomeArticles',
'pfcLoginManagement',
'pfcModalDependency',
'pfcDirectives']);

pfcModule.config([
'$routeProvider',
'authProvider',
'$httpProvider',
'$locationProvider',
'jwtInterceptorProvider',
'paginationTemplateProvider',
function ($routeProvider, authProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider, jwtInterceptorProvider, paginationTemplateProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/home', { templateUrl: './views/home.html', controller: 'pfcHomeArticlesCtrl' }).
        when('/categories/:articlecategoryID/:articlecategoryName', { templateUrl: './views/categories.html', controller: 'pfcArticlesCategoryCtrl' }).
        when('/article/:articleTitle/:articleID', { templateUrl: './views/article.html', controller: 'pfcArticleIDCtrl' }).
        when('/add-article', { templateUrl: './views/add-article.html', controller: 'pfcArticlePostCtrl', requiresLogin: true }).
        when('/login', { templateUrl: './views/login.html', controller: 'loginPageCtrl' }).
        when('/termsandconditions', { templateUrl: './views/terms.html' }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-ZUMO-APPLICATION'] = '1111111111111111111';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'Application/json';
    authProvider.init({
        domain: 'aurl.com',
        clientID: '1111111111111111',
        callbackURL: location.href,
        loginUrl: '/login'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

    jwtInterceptorProvider.tokenGetter = function (store) {
        return store.get('token');
    }

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('jwtInterceptor');

    // Pagination provider
    paginationTemplateProvider.setPath('js/libs/dirPagination.tpl.html');


}])

.run(function ($rootScope, auth, store, jwtHelper, $location) {
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function () {
    if (!auth.isAuthenticated) {
        var token = store.get('token');
        if (token) {
            if (!jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)) {
                auth.authenticate(store.get('profile'), token);
            } else {
                $location.path('/login');
            }
        }
    }

});
});
```

Comment: do you have a nav controller initialized in the index.html?  I don't see one.  I do see a controller in your view rendering.

Comment: I have the App initialized but no controller in index.html. I can add one wrapping the nav if that will make a difference

Comment: Why did this receive a downvote?

Comment: I don't know, it wasn't me.  Hey do you have any CSS besides bootstrap?  I actually had this same problem today with collapse and it was from styling on nav elements. Try removing any extra styling except bootstrap and see if it works.

Comment: No worries. I didn't think it was you, You have been extremely helpful/patient. I have a custom css that is loaded after boostrap. I will give that a try when I get home and will post back.

Comment: I updated my answer with what may be the problem.  I am more inclined to think now that it is css because working code when put into your app doesn't appear to work, but the collapse isn't really anything but css.

Comment: It was worth the attempt, but even removing all CSS but bootstrap leaves the same issue, the dropdown collapses but not the entire menu...

Comment: Is it worth using bootstrap and angularUI in my App or would that create conflicts? (ex. Bootstrap for the menu, AngularUI for the rest).

Comment: I just re-read your OP...

Does this function the way you want:
http://plnkr.co/edit/SFvhPD3tWvBlYWZgrzaG?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to cause the menu to collapse when you click one of the links you can toggle the value of `isCollapsed` with ng-click.  The reason it was collapsing when inside a view was likely because it was actually reloading the navigation, not collapsing it.

Modify your navigation like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li ng-click="isCollapsed=!isCollapsed"><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
    <li" class="dropdown" data-ng-class="{ open : dd1 }" data-ng-init="dd1 = false" data-ng-click="dd1 = !dd1">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false" href="#">Categories <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li ng-click="isCollapsed=!isCollapsed"><a href="/categories/1/cat1">cat1</a></li>
            <li ng-click="isCollapsed=!isCollapsed"><a href="/categories/2/cat2">cat2</a></li>
            <li ng-click="isCollapsed=!isCollapsed"><a href="/categories/5/cat3">cat3</a></li>
            <li ng-click="isCollapsed=!isCollapsed"><a href="/categories/4/cat4">cat4</a></li>
            <li ng-click="isCollapsed=!isCollapsed"><a href="/categories/6/cat5">cat5</a></li>
            <li ng-click="isCollapsed=!isCollapsed"><a href="/categories/3/cat6">cat6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li ng-click="isCollapsed=!isCollapsed"><a href="/add-article">Add Article Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SFvhPD3tWvBlYWZgrzaG?p=preview)

Comment: That's what I thought as well. I just tried wrapping the nav in a controller, but it doesn't collapse. The dropdown does, but not the rest

Comment: Any ideas of why it's only closing the dropdown and not the entire menu?

Comment: check the plunker...it's collapsing fine.

Comment: I am using Angular UI not Bootstrap. Does that make a difference?

Comment: angular ui-bootstrap?

Comment: have you included the bootstrap css?

Comment: check the demo again.  I changed it to use ui-bootstrap instead of the bootstrap.js.  Works fine.

Comment: Thanks, I will test it more once I'm back online

Comment: I can't believe I am still stuck. Inspecting my code it is adding the scope element properly: <div data-ng-include="'templates/topmenu.html'" class="data-ng-scope">. I updated my post with how I am calling scripts in the head.

Comment: load scripts before the </body> tag.  Put your app.js above other app scripts.

Comment: what about your css?  You loading bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap is loaded, and it works when my nav is part of views. Since I have multiple controllers, shouldn't app.js be loaded last?

Comment: no...It actually should be throwing errors because you are loading modules before your app is defined.  I wonder if it's because of defer.

Comment: The defer is removed and I placed them back to the bottom of the body, but same result. I am adding my app.js to my original post.

Comment: I have updated my post. When I inserted your code which works in the plunker, it gave me the same issue of the dropdown collapsing but not the entire navbar (which is desired)

Comment: That did it! and makes complete sense regarding it being reloaded on view change versus in the index. I can rest easy knowing that 1) it works 2) the reason why it works!